# hive configuration hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats does not exists

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-configuration

I am using hive version 3.1.1 and when I try to set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true. I get following error. is hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats is not available in this hive version?

> Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: hive configuration hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats does not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats` configuration property was removed in [Jira HIVE-17932](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17932) as of Hive 3.0.0

> Disabling the fetching of partition
> stats(`hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats`) may cause problematic cases to
> arise for partitioned tables...the user might just want to disable the
> **cbo** instead tweaking the fetching of partition stats.